# Класс для загрузки файлов на сервер

Tags: php

Посоветуйте нормальный класс для загрузки файлов на сервер

Comment: На phpclasses.org много всего. Может что найдете то что Вам больше всего подходит.

Comment: Вы критерии нормальности класса по Вашим меркам напишите, а то так Вам любой класс подойдет...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm